# An old short story: man goes into a fortune-teller's tent, glasses knocked off

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story starts with a man going into a fortune teller's tent; a dangling tassel knocks his glasses off, there is a brief flash. The story then has a flashback: some people are trying to capture(?) someone for some reason but he has very good (hypnotic?) defenses. They learn he is pretending to be a fortune teller, and the protagonist is given a pair of glasses to protect him against being hypnotised. He is told not to remove the glasses under any circumstances. The story ends as it began: he goes into the fortune teller's tent; a dangling tassel knocks his glasses off, there is a brief flash...

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember? For example, when did you read this? Don't forget to register your account and take the [tour]!

Comment: Oh, drat.  I've read this.  I have no idea who wrote it, or what the title was.  I do remember that the book I read it in had a section from the author explaining how he had constructed the story.  Something about how telling the story in a linear time fashion would have been boring, but by starting at that point in the action the reader would be pulled into the story and much more likely to read the backstory and finish the whole thing rather than quit because it wasn't interesting enough.

Comment: Oh, drat. I've read this. Fortune teller is an escaped rogue robot. Protagonist is trying to capture it and is wearing anti hypnosis glases. His assistant, named Tharn, has a gun that will unhygienic the protagonist, if he can get a good shot. Robot gives protagonist a box he says will put protag in mental rapport with future guy who will give help. In reality box just let's protag access his own memories.

Comment: @ people who've read it , is it 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Ending_(short_story) ? ([full text apparently](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/SciFi_Fantasy/Science%20Fiction/Kuttner%2C%20Henry/Kuttner%2C%20Henry%20-%20Happy%20Ending.txt))

Comment: Yes that's the story.

Answer (score 21):

### [Happy Ending](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69891) by Henry Kuttner

Quarra Vee and his faithful sidekick, Tharn, travel into the past to capture a rogue robot. The "past" in this case is our present time. The robot is in a circus, pretending  to be a gypsy fortune teller.

The robot has telepathic brain washing powers. Vee wears anti brainwashing glasses, but they are knocked off by a rope. The robot hypnotizes Vee in to thinking Vee is a native of our present, instead of a visitor from the future.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the one. (But it's Henry Kuttner, not "Kutcher".) For some reason I can't mark this as "answered"...

Comment: @Lurker Please [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can accept this answer.